# MVC 4 Database not seeding

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-4, visual-studio-2012, model-view-controller

I am using code first in order to create the database for my project and I am having troubling getting my database to see,I am getting a null value error(i assume this means that the seed data is not seeding and the db is empty).
Heres my code,any insight would be great:

Models:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations;
using System.Data.Entity;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web;

namespace rad_302_ca.Models
{
    public class SeederMethod : DropCreateDatabaseAlways<AppDB>
    {
        protected override void Seed(AppDB context)
        {
            var newlocations = new List<Location>()
            {
                new Location() { LocationName="Home",LocationAddress="Rathbrughan,Sligo"},
                new Location() {LocationName="Farm",LocationAddress="Mountcharles,Sligo"},
                new Location() {LocationName="College", LocationAddress="Sligo IT,Sligo"}
            };

            newlocations.ForEach(lo => context.Locations.Add(lo));
            context.SaveChanges();
        }
    }
    public class Location
    {
        [Key]
        public int LocationID { get; set; }
        public string LocationName { get; set; }
        public string LocationAddress { get; set; }
    }

    public class AppDB : DbContext
    {
        public DbSet<Location> Locations;
         public AppDB()
            : base("AppCon") { Database.SetInitializer(new SeederMethod());}

    }
}
```

The global:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web;
using System.Web.Http;
using System.Web.Mvc;
using System.Web.Optimization;
using System.Web.Routing;
using rad_302_ca.Models;
using System.Data.Entity;

namespace rad_302_ca
{
    // Note: For instructions on enabling IIS6 or IIS7 classic mode, 
    // visit http://go.microsoft.com/?LinkId=9394801

    public class WebApiApplication : System.Web.HttpApplication
    {
        protected void Application_Start()
        {
            AreaRegistration.RegisterAllAreas();

            WebApiConfig.Register(GlobalConfiguration.Configuration);
            FilterConfig.RegisterGlobalFilters(GlobalFilters.Filters);
            RouteConfig.RegisterRoutes(RouteTable.Routes);
            BundleConfig.RegisterBundles(BundleTable.Bundles);
            Database.SetInitializer(new SeederMethod());
        }
    }
}
```

The con string in web.config

```
 <add name="AppCon" connectionString="Data Source=(LocalDb)\v11.0;Initial Catalog=aspnet-radCa1302;Integrated Security=SSPI;"
```

Update: index page where the error is happening(also the ieumerable at the top)

```
 @model IEnumerable<rad_302_ca.Models.Location>

<div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-2">
        <div class="panel panel-info">
            <div class="panel-heading">Locations</div>
            <div class="panel-body" style="overflow-x:hidden;height:300px">
                <table class="table table-condensed" id="loctbl">

                    @foreach (var item in Model)
                    {
                        <tr style="cursor:pointer"><td>@item.LocationID</td></tr>
                    }

                </table>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
```

the error: 
Object reference not set to an instance of an object.

Comment: Where is the null reference exception thrown?

Comment: on the index page when i try to boot up the question,ill update the code t show this,overlooked it

Comment: Stupid question, but are you fetching the data in your controller?

Comment: Yes i am,i have this to create an instanace AppDB db = new AppDB(); and then i was trying to use this  ///return View(db.Locations.ToList()); to get a list out,but then(and still) i am getting a value can not be null error